# Mysql - "Order by" does not work using "CONCAT"

Tags: mysql, concatenation, sql-order-by

I have been looking for a "why" to this.
In this query I am trying to show results but previously I make a comparison of a URL field of one table and the URL field of another table (I use CONCAT because the URLs are not exactly the same) but when I try to add the "Order by ... "the statement takes a long time to respond until the server cuts my connection.

```
SELECT id, url, title MATCH(title, tags, category) AGAINST('white dogs') as score 
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Deleted_Items
ON Deleted_Items.url LIKE CONCAT(Items.url , '%') 
WHERE Deleted_Items.url IS NULL 
AND MATCH(title, tags, category) AGAINST('white dogs' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: You need to reference the table on your select, otherwise it will interpret as duplicated and will search forever until time out

Comment: I did the test by adding the name of the table to each column but the result was the same (Items.*)

Answer (score 1):

The join condition that employs CONCAT() isn't `sargable` and hence inherently inefficient plus sorting on a computation. Perhaps help it along by persisting the data to a temporary table e.g.

```
INSERT INTO some_temp_tbl_name (id, url, title, tags, category) 
SELECT i.id, i.url, i.title, i.tags, i.category
FROM Items i
LEFT JOIN Deleted_Items d ON d.url LIKE CONCAT(i.url , '%') 
WHERE d.url IS NULL
```

Then perform the match and order from that table.